# Flutter: Cant align row items correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, row

I have a row im trying to align correctly. It holds two cards id like to be spaced evenly, and an icon button aligned to the right side of the row.

With just the cards using the following code,

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: [
    Card(...),
    Card(...),
  ],
),
```

it looks like this:
[image]

But When i add an icon button with the following code

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: [
    Card(),
    Card(),
    Spacer(),
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.close),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
    ),
  ],
),
```

it looks like this:
[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A note from [`Spacer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html)

> `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,` or `MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly` will not have any visible effect: the Spacer has taken up all of the additional space, therefore there is none left to redistribute.

As for the you are trying to archive, I am using nested row for this

```dart
 Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Card(
            child: Text("A"),
          ),
          Card(
            child: Text("A"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.close),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by the `Spacer` widget.
The `Spacer` widget will use all the space available by default.

You can remove the `Spacer` widget so all your child will be evenly-spaced.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the ***spacer*** widget, ***Spacer*** widget by default took the whole width. give it a specific width, instead use sizedBox and give it a width for horizontal space.